# Best way to complete the merge process

Tags: merge

I am trying to clean my org and need to merge duplicate accounts. I am using SOAP to first find out duplicates and then merge them.
I am concerned about the downtime.

I am looking for recommendations on doing this in a best way which will speed up the process with accuracy maintained.

Comment: how are you going to decide which Account should be the merge winner?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this email finds you well.

You can clean-up/sync your Org's easily by using AutoRABIT's Data Loader Pro function. For both Data as well as Metadata.

www.autorabit.com

Let me know how it goes.

Sincerely,
Simon